# interactivly resizable rows in QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, pyqt4

In a QTableWidget I can configure the rows to be resizable by the user on run time by setting the `verticalHeader`'s `resizeMode` to `Interactive` like this:

```
    table.verticalHeader().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Interactive)
```

How would I configure a similar behavior for `QListWidget`? Unfortunately the `QListWidget` `resizeMode` does not have an `Interactive` item and I haven't found anything similar.

The best would be to configure it for the whole list but when it's possible for single rows/items that would be ok, too.

Answer (score 3):

As [doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistview.html) said:

> This view does not display horizontal or vertical headers; to display
>   a list of items with a horizontal header, use QTreeView instead.

So you should use `QTreeView` (or `QTreeWidget`) with one column and maybe with specific style.

Another approach. There are no header, so you can provide some instrument (dialog window, slider or something else) where user will be able to change row height, to change row height you should just use `setData()` and set `QSize()` to `Qt::SizeHintRole`. For example:

```
ui->listWidget->model()->setData(ui->listWidget->currentIndex(),
                                 QSize(40,40),Qt::SizeHintRole);
```